# In JavaScript I can't seem to make an if statement for if an Boolean is True/False

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

I'm trying to make a server, but I keep getting `Syntax Error: "unexpected identifier"`...
I have done things like this:

```
if (AFK === true

alert("server AFK")

}
```

```
if Boolean(AFK)

alert("server AFK")

}
```

```
if (AFK

alert("server AFK")

}
```

The same error comes up...

I have a Boolean as well, so I had to put this:

```
var AFK = true
```

It is a thing to tell you if the server is AFK or not.
The server is NOT working yet, I'm just seeing some errors with detecting boolean values...

Any way you could help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) is:

```
if (condition)
   statement1
```

So you should change it to:

```
if (AFK === true) {
  alert("server AFK")
}
```